# format number in react input

Tags: reactjs, input, format

I need format an input in react, add suffix "g". For the result input it´s ok  but for input1 and input2 when I change the type the number to text it does not work correctly. Link codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-meitner-ez7wo?file=/src/index.js

Thank you very much guys.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function App() {
const [input1, setInput1] = useState(2);
const [input2, setInput2] = useState(3);

const updateInput1 = (event) => {
  const inputValue1 = event.target.value
  setInput1(parseInt(inputValue1))
}

const updateInput2 = (event) => {
  const inputValue2 = event.target.value
  setInput2(parseInt(inputValue2))
}

  const addInputs =()=> input1 + input2;

  return <>
  <label>
    Input1
  </label>
  <input
  type="number"
  onChange={updateInput1}
  value={input1}
  >
  </input>

  <label>
    Input2
  </label>
  <input
  type="number"
  onChange={updateInput2}
  value={input2}
  >
  </input>

  <label>
    Result
  </label>
  <input
  type="text"
  value={addInputs() + "g"}
  >
  </input>
  </>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to add them together so if input1 = 5 and input2 = 10, result should output '15g'

Comment: yes that is, but above all I am interested in giving it the format, since the function is only an example

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.value` is returning a string. All you have to do to fix your code is convert both inputs back into ints before setting them like so:

```
 const updateInput1 = (event) => {
    const inputValue1 = event.target.value
    setInput1(parseInt(inputValue1))
 }

 const updateInput2 = (event) => {
    const inputValue2 = event.target.value
    setInput2(parseInt(inputValue2))
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much, now it works fine but i need the format, the suffix g

Comment: How would you like to format the suffix g? I'd be happy to help!

Comment: as in the input result: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-meitner-ez7wo?file=/src/index.js:0-848

Comment: are you wanting it to look like 
Input1 2g
Input2 3g Result 5G?

Comment: You cannot have non-numeric characters in an input of type="number" I can show you how to format it within an input of type="text" but you lose the +1, -1 functionality

Comment: Thank you very much that is what I thought, in text format will the function add work?

Comment: yes, as you don't have any non-numeric characters in the value before parseInt(). Ei. if you have '5g' you must remove the 'g' to have only '5' before converting it back to and int.